# Pros and cons of using this minimalist system?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, authentication, registration

I'm trying to create a very simple login system for my app. Would it be possible to have a minimalist system for login/signup where there are fields for the username and password and then allow them choose between logging in or signing up with those fields? Versus having them choose initially between logging in or signing up and then going through a different process depending on which option they chose?

A simple login system similar I'm talking about was used in the Yo app. The difference is that they separated their login and sign up but the fields that the user has to enter are the same, so I was wondering if I could simplify the process further.

I was wondering what the pros and cons of using this sort of system were, and if this is a good option for my simple app.

Comment: How do you know if the user made a typo?

Comment: I didn't consider that, I just wanted them to be able to make an account very easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to not even have a login flow but it's hard for me to recommend that given I don't know much about your product. If you're building against CloudKit you don't even need to present a registration or login form if the phone is connected to an iCloud account.

I suspect the simplest flow is just asking for the user's email address and basing their identity on that. If the email exists in your system you can prompt them to enter a password, if not then you can prompt them with whatever additional information you're requiring for registration; hopefully not much :)

If the value if your product is clear then people will endure a little setup cost, if it isn't then you may want to fix that before worrying about the signup process.